# Do Iron Man suits sport waste management systems?

Tags: marvel, technology, iron-man

Obviously, it is difficult to be an effective superhero if you need to take potty breaks.  And Iron Man's suit affords a unique opportunity to fix this problem.

Do we have evidence of integrated waste management systems?  (And what about hydration and nutrition, if that is not too unrelated an add-on.)

Comment: In iron man 2 he urinates in the suit whilst drunk at the party

Comment: Tony's later suits open quickly, and he wears street clothes underneath them. This doesn't rule out the possibility that the suits have extra features usually left unused, but I think it suggests that Tony thinks of the suits as things for short-term occupation, like cars.

Comment: @Criggie, out-of-universe?   I think we can reasonably assume the on-set costumes don't have waste management systems.   If you mean, is the explanation based on in-movie/comic evidence vs. supplementary materials or commentary, then anything is okay, but its canonicity will be considered appropriately.

Comment: Re: out-of-universe, given how complicated and time-consuming it can be to get performers into and out of full-body costumes, a built-in waste management system seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 34):

The suit, or at least the Mark IV suit, does have waste management systems which is then filtered and can be used to drink. In the *Iron Man 2* party scene we see Tony pee in the suit and later comment to Pepper about it.

> **Tony:** *[To crowd]* You know, the question I get asked most often is, “Tony, how do you go to the bathroom in the suit?” *[pauses]* Just like that.
>
> [...]
>
> **Pepper:** You just peed in the suit.
>
> **Tony:** I know. It has a filtration system.
>
> **Pepper:** It’s not sexy.
>
> **Tony:** You could drink that water.
>
> <sub>*Iron Man 2*</sub>

The Mark 50 suit we see in *Avengers: Infinity War* is made of nano technology that can completely reform its shape as needed. Therefore, it is possible that this suit can actually form a zipper so Tony doesn't have to take off the suit on the job for a quick pit stop.

Nutrition wise, the helmet on all his suits, or at least the face plate, can come off quite easily and so it seems like he can easily eat with the suit on. In fact we regularly see him eating in the suit. For example, in *Iron Man 2* again we see him eating a doughnut in a doughnut.

[image: Tony eating in the suit]

The Space Armor, or Model 5, in the comics is also noted as having a catheter and food supply storage in *The Iron Manual*.

> [image: The Iron Manual with details of the suits features, relevant parts quoted below]
>
> Space capable - using Model III booster - can endure 2 days in orbit, food and catheterization possible.

Comment: Tony could have just as easily been lying to Pepper. He has been known to do that, constantly does that, and even more probability when he's drunk off his rocks. Either we consider the entire conversation as him drunk blabbering, or not.

Comment: @Stark07As I said to you in your previous comment on your answer there's a major difference between a private conversation and drunkenly showing off and boasting to a crowd.

Comment: Are you sure that Tony Stark understands that difference?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yeah considering his attitude actually gets a bit more sheepish when he's talking to Pepper "to the side".

Comment: @Stark07 It is *Pepper* who accuses him of peeing in the suit. She would only do that if she is reasonably sure he *could* do that. So its not only Tonys testimony, its Peppers. Therefore I'd say its safe to say the suit has such a system.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it does.

*Iron Man 2* party scene:

Tony says:

> "The question I get asked most often is 'Tony how do you go to
>   bathroom in the suit"

After which there is a small pause, and Tony says

> "Just like that"

Implying that his suit does have built in waste management systems.

There is also a later scene where he tells Pepper:

> Iron Man : [leaning in to kiss her]  Come on, you know you want to.
>   Give me another smooch.
>
> Pepper Potts : You're not going to be happy about this.
>
> Iron Man : Come on, you know you want to.
>
> Pepper Potts : You just peed in the suit.
>
> Iron Man : I know, **it has a filtration system.**
>
> Pepper Potts : It's not sexy.
>
> Iron Man : You could drink that water.

Combining both these instances, I believe we can safely conclude that Tony does indeed have some sort of a waste management built-in into his suit.

With the latest bleeding edge armour, this becomes even more simple.

Comment: It should be noted that he is drunk and entertaining a group of people. I am pretty sure he's making a joke since no human pees or poos that fast.

Comment: @Parrotmaster, don't think we want to go into a debate on how quickly you can do that, but yes they can.

Comment: @Gnemlock The general point is that, that was more of a joke than anything else. For all we know the suit _doesn't_ have waste management and cos he's drunk he just wees himself.

Comment: I don't see much evidence that this was drunk blabbering, and it makes total sense from a design perspective that the suit have a waste mgmt system. And we have a scene from the film saying it does. There's even a later scene where he explains to Pepper how the suit recycles the water from the urine!

Comment: After the update to add in the next part of the scene with Pepper this makes the answer more complete +1